# Push Messages from AWS Lambda to Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, aws-lambda

I have a kafka machine running in AWS which consists of several topics. 
I have the following Lambda function which Produces a message and push that to one of the kafka topic.

```js
import json from kafka
import KafkaClient from kafka
import SimpleProducer from kafka
import KafkaProducer

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    kafka = KafkaClient("XXXX.XXX.XX.XX:XXXX")
    print(kafka)
    producer = SimpleProducer(kafka, async = True)
    print(producer)
    task_op = {
        "'message": "Hai, Calling from AWS Lambda"
    }
    print(json.dumps(task_op))
    producer.send_messages("topic_atx_ticket_update",json.dumps(task_op).encode('utf-8'))
    print(producer.send_messages)
    return ("Messages Sent to Kafka Topic")
```

But I see messages are not pushed as i expected.

Note: No Issues in Roles and Policies, Connectivity.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your code.

Comment: in lambda_handler.py file
I am creating  a kafka Client and using Kafka Producer API to produce messages.
From my local laptop i was able to push the messages to the kafka topic

Comment: Can you add the code in your question?

Comment: You say "no issues in… connectivity" -> can you detail how you have determined this? A common problem in this scenario is mis-configurtion of the Kafka listeners.

Comment: import json

from kafka import KafkaClient

from kafka import SimpleProducer

from kafka import KafkaProducer

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    kafka = KafkaClient("XXXX.XXX.XX.XX:XXXX")

    print(kafka)
    producer = SimpleProducer(kafka, async=True)
    print(producer)
    task_op= {"'message":"Hai, Calling from AWS Lambda"}
    print(json.dumps(task_op))
    
    producer.send_messages("topic_atx_ticket_update", json.dumps(task_op).encode('utf-8'))
    print(producer.send_messages)
    return("Messages Sent to Kafka Topic")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Creating a Kafka Producer object,

```
producer = SimpleProducer(kafka, async=True)
```

"async" String should be False, like

```
producer = SimpleProducer(kafka, async=False)
```

Then,

you can send the Kafka Message to a topic from AWS Lambda.